# Error ANT command in OS Mavericks

Tags: java, android, ant, osx-mavericks

today I have update my OS to Mavericks from Lion and now the ANT command doesn't works :(
this is the error:

iMac:$ ant
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin/java
iMac:$

I tried to write this:

export JAVA_HOME="$(/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Comman‌​ds/java_home)" in ~/.bash_profile but I have always the same error... :(

There some people can help me?

Answer (score 1):

ok, I have resolved my issue:

- download new apacheant from http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi
- remove old apache reference from ~/.bash_profile
- create new export ANT_HOME with the new downloaded apache, inside ~/.bash_profile

Bye!